# permission doesn't work in view method [Django restframework]

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using `django restframework` to do some permission requiring work. What I want to do is make a whole permission require in my view and a different permission require in my specified method. And below is my trial with some main codes.

> 1 basic view

```
class VSAccount(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MAccount.objects.all().filter(active=True)
    serializer_class = DEFAULT_ACCOUNT_SERIALIZER_CLASS
    filter_backends = (SearchFilter, DjangoFilterBackend)
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, BaseDataPermission, ]
    filter_class = FAccount
    search_fields = []
    module_perm = 'account.get_account'
    #   1) add module_perm account.get_account required for whole view.


    @action(methods=['get'], url_path='list-with-daily-spends', detail=False)
    def list_daily_spend(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.module_perm = 'account.get_account-list-with-daily-spend'
        # 2) add  module_perm for this method only but doesn't work here
        self.permission_classes = [BaseDataPermission, ]
        self.serializer_class = SAccountListItemDaily
        ret_data = super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)
        self.serializer_class = DEFAULT_ACCOUNT_SERIALIZER_CLASS
        return ret_data
```

> 2 customer permission

```
class BaseDataPermission(BasePermission):

    authenticated_users_only = True

    def has_perms(self, user, perm):
        user_perms = user.get_all_permissions()
        print(perm) # it's always what I write in viewset? 
        if perm in user_perms:
            return True
        return False

    def has_permission(self, request, view):

        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return True

        assert hasattr(view, "module_perm"), "need module_perm"

        assert isinstance(view.module_perm, str), "module_perm should be a string"

        if getattr(view, '_ignore_model_permissions', False):
            return True

        if hasattr(view, 'get_queryset'):
            queryset = view.get_queryset()
        else:
            queryset = getattr(view, 'queryset', None)

        assert queryset is not None, (
            'Cannot apply DjangoModelPermissions on a view that '
            'does not set `.queryset` or have a `.get_queryset()` method.'
        )

        return (
                request.user and
                (request.user.is_authenticated or not self.authenticated_users_only) and
                self.has_perms(request.user, view.module_perm)
        )
```

My question is why I rewrite the `moudle_perm` in method `list_daily_spend`, the permission required is still `account.get_account` which I write in `VSAccount` and how can I get the expected result?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the value of **`self.permission_classes`** will not get you there, you need to override the **`get_permissions(...)`** method of ModelViewSet as,

```
class VSAccount(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # rest of your code

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action == 'list_daily_spend':
            self.module_perm = 'account.get_account-list-with-daily-spends'
            permission_classes = [BaseDataPermission, ]
            return [permission() for permission in permission_classes]
        return super().get_permissions()
```

Alternatively, you can set the permission classes in your **`action`** decorator as,

```
class VSAccount(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    @action(methods=['get'],
            url_path='list-with-daily-spends',
            detail=False,
            permission_classes=[BaseDataPermission, ], module_perm = 'account.get_account-list-with-daily-spends')
    def list_daily_spend(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # your code
```

Comment: Thanks for your replying, should I add `module_perm ` in each suggestion answer above?